# Two pressure regulators on one zone?

Tags: irrigation

I have what looks like a filter and pressure regulator inline with the control valve for two of my zones.  These are the zones that are supposed to be low pressure.  But when I recently checked the pressure on the two zones, one was at 40 and the other near 60.  So I think the regulators have failed (they are lik e7 years old.  Replacing them in the box would be a pain for sure. But the zones surface to go to the low pressure sprinklers.  So I could just put new pressure regulators there.  But one of them splits in two underground.  Can I put a regulator on each point where it surfaces (so total of 3).  Or is there some physics that will mess up the regulation?

Comment: Does your control valve have a pressure limit?

Comment: I am sure it does... But I don't know it.  It's in the water box too and I can't see any thing written on it.  That said, the valve is before the pressure regulators so even if they were functional, they wouldn't help it.  And I have 4 other zones that don't have regulators involved, but the valve is the same, so I know the control valve can handle.  If I remember right the full pressure is up around 80, so the pressure reducers are still reducing some, just not as far down as they should be.

Comment: Are you checking when there is flow? Over time some regulators bleed by and that can be the source of the pressure, since you have a filter I would not expect obstructions causing the regulators to fail have you tried adjusting them? Adding another regulator really would not cause a pressure problem but at some point multiple regulators can limit the flow causing the final pressure to be two low.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when there is flow".  But I think so.  The zone I tested on has two outputs.  One has 4 mini sprinklers on it and the other is where I attached the gauge.  I guess that could make the final pressure reading low?  That was the zone with the 40.  The zone with the 60 has 3 drippers that were active while I measured.  So maybe the real pressure is 60 in both or something.  That would means the reducers are still reducing from 80 to 60 though.  Do they fail that way, or are they all or nothing?